# Windows Update Catalog has several identical display drivers with different update IDs for onboard AMD Radeon 3000 GPU

Tags: windows-10, gpu, amd-radeon, display-driver, on-board-peripheral

I have an old Asus Essentio PC (CM1630) with an onboard AMD Radeon 3000 GPU. The Windows Update Catalog shows several display drivers that are the same for *"Windows 10 1903 and later,"* namely *"Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. - Display - 27.20.14524.0"* but have different update IDs.

When you click the driver's name, the details appear. The OS versions, AMD GPU devices, driver numbers, driver date, inf files, driver file size, supported hardware IDs, etc., are identical.

The only different thing is the "Update ID." Microsft says update IDs are a type of GUID assigned to a given update at publication time.

Here's the link: [AMD Radeon 3000 GPU Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ATI%20Radeon%203000%20Graphics)

I just want to obtain the last known display driver for this particular GPU for Windows 10 for archival purposes (not the default generic display driver). As for the manufacturer, it became a legacy item over ten years ago.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not have an answer for you about what the ***Update ID***'s point is. It seems like some sort of way to target updating on top of specific updates.

But, this all doesn't matter!

All of those are the exact same download (exact as in 100% the same, even the same .cab filename.) So take any of them and you gave the latest one.